# Recursive function that divides two numbers, using successive subtraction

Tags: c

I have tried but failed to do so. Could I have a push in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, how you failed, and clarify the question?

Comment: Why is this being closed as "not a real question"? Seems perfectly valid to me.

Answer (score 6):

I should stress first that this is usually a spectacularly bad usage for recursion. The best recursive solutions tend to reduce the "search space" of the solution rather quickly, such as a binary search removing half the remaining search space with every iteration.

Repeated subtraction will, if the subtrahend is relatively small compared to the minuend (where `minuend - subtrahend` gives you the difference), result in a great many recursive calls and quite possibly exhaust your stack space.

---

Having said that, the solution below is in pseudo-code only, since it's probably homework:

```
def divu (a, b):
    if a < b return 0
    return divu (a - b, b) + 1
```

It works by repeatedly subtracting `b` from `a`, and going down a level, until you can no longer subtract `b` from `a` without going negative. Then it returns up the recursion tree, adding 1 for each level you went down.

This will only work for non-negative values of `a` and positive values of `b` (hence the `divu` name for unsigned), though fixing it for negatives and divide-by-zero is only a little extra work.

Some hints for handling signs and errors:

- Detect straight up if b is equal to zero and exit with an error, exception, or some other mechanism.
- Treat `-a / -b` as `a / b`.
- Treat `-a / b` as `-(a / b)`.
- Treat `a / -b` as `-(a / b)`.
- Otherwise, just work out `a / b`.

It's possible to handle those special cases in a single recursive call but it adds unnecessary checking at *each* level of recursion. It's probably more efficient to provide a checking function `div` which can then call `divu` to do the recursive bit, something like:

```
def div (a, b):
    if b == 0
        exit with error
    if a < 0 and b < 0:
        return divu (-a, -b)
    if a < 0:
        return -divu (-a, b)
    if b < 0:
        return -divu (a, -b)
    return divu (a, b)
```